# Grails: Offset and Max on many-to-many relationship

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

I following two domain classes with many to many relationship

```
Question{
    has many 'Tag'
}

Tag{
    has many 'Question'
}
```

now, I want to retrieve only 3 questions each time using max and offset property,
how do I do that from controller?

Comment: Too vague... show us the query you are using that gives you all the results and we may be able to suggest an improvement.

Answer (score 0):

```
Question.list(max: YourMaxValue, offset: YourOffsetValue)
```

to get Question from Tag

```
Tag tag ..
tag.Question.list(max: YourMaxValue, offset: YourOffsetValue)
```